# Why are my Time Series residuals similar to my stationary data?

Tags: time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to fit an ARMA model to the historical GBP/USD rates for the last 10 years. when I perform a one-step ahead prediction, the hit rate and other metrics come out fine. However, I am having trouble evaluating the performance of the fitted model's data.

When I plot the residuals from the fitted model and the fitted values vs the actual stationary data (i.e. I differenced it to make it stationary), the residuals closely match the stationary data, and the fitted values seem to represent the residuals.
It's very confusing, especially with the good accuracy of the forecasts. Could there be a fundamental problem with the ARIMA function and the statsmodels.tsa library in python?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps ask on the Cross Validated Stack.

Comment: There are no real problems with statsmodels arima. I guess what you see is the expected behavior. The residual plot will look similar to the original plot if there is no information in the data about what is plotted. (But that's not possible to tell from the provided information.)

Comment: For example, it could mean that a ARIMA model is not doing much better than assuming a random walk in one-step ahead forecasting, which is quite common for financial data.

Comment: @Josef do you mind elaborating more please? This is for a 3rd year project so I'm still a bit of a novice here. Thanks!

Comment: @SolarMike do you mind posting a link to the stack please? I'm a bit new to stack overflow. Thanks!

Comment: Check in the list of Stacks.